# How to plot a total of multiple rows across a timeline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show change in job numbers within certain time period. Ideally, I'd like to use a [ggplot2 geom_dotplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html) and then color those dots by the column that they are in  for that month. One idea I have not tried yet: do I need to reformat my data using tidyr from a wide to a long format in order to plot this?

Example data

```
Month       Finance       Tech        Construction     Manufacturing
Jan         14,000        6,800       11,000           17,500
Feb         11,500        8,400       9,480            15,000
Mar         15,250        4,200       7,200            12,400
Apr         12,000        6,400       10,300           8,500
```

My current r code attempt: I know that I need to fill the dot color by a factor of industry type. Maybe I have to have the data in a long format to do so.

```
library(tidyverse)
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackgroups = TRUE, binwidth = 1000, binpositions = "all") +
  theme_light()
g
```

Here's how the plot I'm trying to make could look. Ideally I'd like to bin the dots as one dot per 1000 in the column value. Is that possible?

[image]

Thank you for taking the time to help someone who is new to R and is studying in school. Much appreciated as always,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not get the geom_dotplot to work, the y-axis always comes out wrong. Try something like, first pivot long and we repeat the Month+category per every 1000, note this solution below rounds up:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

test = pivot_longer(dat,-Month,names_to="category") %>% 
group_by(Month,category) %>% 
summarize(bins=ceiling(value/ 1000)) %>% 
uncount(bins)
```

If you would prefer to round down to the nearest 1000, use `floor()` instead of `ceiling()` .

Then plot:

```
test$Month = factor(test$Month,levels=dat[,1])

test %>% ggplot(aes(x=Month,y=1,col=category)) + 
geom_point(position=position_stack()) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::number_format(scale=1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks amazing, I will try right now. @StupidWolf you save the day for me once again.

Comment: Hi @JacksonWalker, I just realized one thing.. if it is 6,800, would you have 6 or 7 dots? Right now, the code above rounds everything down.. so  6,800 will give 6. I can edit my answer to round up

Comment: Yes @Stupidwolf please do edit it to round up, thank you!

Comment: @JacksonWalker done.. see above, for example Jan, tech you get 7balls

Comment: thank you @stupidwolf, when I run `test = pivot_longer(data1,-Month,names_to="category") %>% 
  group_by(Month,category) %>% 
  summarize(bins=ceiling(value/ 1000)) %>% 
  uncount(bins)` I get an error saying Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument. Could this be because my Month column actually has data that reads "Mar 2020" with the years?

Comment: class(data1) results in [1] "data.frame". The data frame looks like this: https://share.getcloudapp.com/nOu8kejA I am running R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) and I am using the latest version of the tidyverse

Comment: I think I should remove the commas in the dataframe, that's probably whats causing the issue. Do you know an easy way to remove them when I import the data into the dataframe @stupidwolf? `if (!exists("data1")) {
  data1 <- read.csv("./convertcsv.csv") %>%
    select(c("Month","Leisure.and.hospitality","Retail.trade","Financial.activities","Professional.and.business.services","Construction","Manufacturing"))
}` In other words, yes the dataframe contains number that contain commas to denote thousands in the observations

Comment: I get "Error: unexpected symbol in " dat[,your columns" when I run `dat = read.csv("./convertcsv.csv",dec=",") ; dat[,your columns] = dat[,your columns]*1000`

Comment: sorry don't include month

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this again, I was able to get dat to be intigers without commas, but when I try to pivot longer with `test = pivot_longer(dat,-Month,names_to="category") %>% 
  group_by(Month,category) %>% 
  summarize(bins=ceiling(value/ 1000)) %>% 
  uncount(bins)` I get the error `Error in 1000 * test = pivot_longer(dat, -Month, names_to = "category") %>%  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212450/discussion-between-jackson-walker-and-stupidwolf).